# Search Substring(specific value) from array index in java

Tags: java, arrays, substring

I want to filter specific text from a specific array in java like

```
String a="code=500,code1=1000"
```

I want to get only 500 from index 0 by searching "code="

Comment: What did you try and what were the results?

Comment: @Vijay Varadan I Tried a.matches(".*code=.*") and it wokred Fine

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to:

Split the String by "," to an array.
Now for each element of the array, do a replaceAll to remove the text before the number.

It might not be the most optimal, but this should work:

```
String[] split = a.split(",");
for (String s: split) {
  String desiredText = s.replaceAll(".+=", "");
}
```

Then you could add the desiredText to a List or whatever it is you want to do with it.